# Facebook Access Token: (null) with Social.framework iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7, facebook-access-token

I've scoured posts regarding this topic, I'm new to the Social.framework/Facebook SDK in iOS. I have followed an example similar to [How to use iOS 6's social framework](https://gist.github.com/veritech/3752113)

I set up an app in Facebook and enabled FB login. My JSON error being (as well as when I go to https://graph.facebook.com/):

```
error =     {
    code = 104;
    message = "An access token is required to request this resource.";
    type = OAuthException;
};
```

and even tried accessing the token via (which gives me null):

```
    // Get the access token, could be used in other scenarios
    ACAccountCredential *fbCredential = [account credential];
    NSString *accessToken = [fbCredential oauthToken];
    NSLog(@"Facebook Access Token: %@", accessToken);
```

When the user starts the app, it immediately jumps to the authorization of facebook data, they press OK to continue. Simple. I've read up on Access Tokens [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).

My question, doesn't the access token get instantiated upon the user hitting OK? Or do I set it up somewhere in the App page on developers.facebook.com? I'm a novice with the Facebook integration and am royally confused on how to solve this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Temperarely , You will not received Facebook Access Token using Facebook Graph API and Social Framework,We all are facing same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: A) the Bundle ID in the developers.facebook.com did not match the Bundle ID in the project, and B) the URL used was

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://graph.facebook.com/search"];
```

and not

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/search"];
```

I hope many can benefit from my sorrows :)